# Common view template files with Wiredesignz HMVC & CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, templates, codeigniter-3, hmvc

> It is actually straightforward. If the code can't find a view file in
>   **application/modules directory** then it look for it in the
>   **application/views directory**. So I didn't have to change anything. The directory structure and the loading calls were correct, the
>   problem was with misspelling and some other part of the code.

How do I have common view template files in Wiredesignz's HMVC & CodeIgniter?
For example, I use header.php and footer.php with every project and I put them in application/views/template directory but with this HMVC setup **when I try to load the view files only the first file gets loaded**.

This is how I am loading the views in the controller class Welcome:

```
$this->load->view ( 'templates/header' );
$this->load->view ( 'welcome_message' );
$this->load->view ( 'templates/footer' );
```

This is the module structure :

```
application > modules 

application > modules > home 

application > modules > home > controllers > Welcome.php

application > modules > home > views  > welcome_message.php


application > views > templates > header.php

application > views > templates > footer.php
```

Comment: Show us your modules folder structure

Answer (score -1):

I came here to search for another query but found you are still struggling through this.
Follow the tutorial from the below link and it will solve most of your doubts.

http://www.kode-blog.com/codeigniter-hmvc/